# how to give different links for a single form submit button using if else conditions

Tags: javascript, html

My webpage does mathematical calculations. I have placed 5 checkboxes on it. Depending upon the selected checkbox I want the page to be directed to a particular link using javascript. How to add these links in the javascript depending upon the checkbox selected?

```
<div id="angl">
    <input type="checkbox" id="ph" onclick='select()' checked><span id="phi1">Phi(φ)</span>
    <input type="checkbox" id="psi"><span id="psi1">Psi(ψ)</span>
    <input type="checkbox" id="omega"><span id="omega1">Omega(ω)</span>
    <input type="checkbox" id="calpha"><span id="calpha1">C-Alpha (C-α)</span>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chi" onchange="ang_type()"><span id="chi1">Chi(χ)</span>
</div>
```

lets say I have 5 links:

> 'phi.pl', 'psi.pl' , 'omega.pl' , 'calpha.pl' , 'chi.pl'

Comment: Can you share some code as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkboxes are used when a user can response choosing more than one answer. So, how are you planning to redirect to several pages, if your user uses more than one? - Sorry, if I didn't understand you correctly.

But if I understood you properly: e.g. user selects something and based on the selection is then redirected to particular link. Then there are options:

1. use jquery and bind this on action
2. use form submit, so when user selects and submits he or she is redirected.

Comment: Checkboxes are a part of form and i have included submit button. but is there any possibity with which i can direct to individual links using javascript?

Comment: Sorry, for misunderstanding, I need to to clarify more: so let's say user checks two checkboxes, would you like to direct user to both of them?

Comment: Thankyou for the response. Those files phi.pl , psi.pl , etc have the calculation part for the selected checkboxes. and yes, i would like to direct to both of them i.e, output of both the files have to printed in a single page. for instance if i select phi output for phi.pl have to printed in the resulting page or if i select both phi and psi , results for both the calculations have to be printed in the resulting page.

Comment: Thank you, now it's clear for me. My recommendations: You may prepare 5 different pages with those files (outputs). Then in the submit just send Ids of those pages as a value. In the new page it will receive values and display needed pages from those 5. They may be displayed in the iframe. Because you already have them in the separate pages. Or you may display all values but according to submit button hide non-required with CSS property using javascript.

Comment: Thanks. i got my result. your replies were very helpful.

Comment: Welcome, happy for you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to this before form actually submit  so either use ajax in below function

```
$('FormSelector').submit(function() {
    //make ajax request base don codition to one of 'phi.pl', 'psi.pl' , 'omega.pl' , 'calpha.pl' , 'chi.pl'.
    return false; // return false to cancel form submit
});
```

or using javascript change form action attribute and then submit do his task by returning true.

```
 $('FormSelector').submit(function() {
     //change attribute action based on condition to one of 'phi.pl', 'psi.pl' , 'omega.pl' , 'calpha.pl' , 'chi.pl'.
     return true; // return false to cancel form submit
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'This' operator.

```js
function savevalue(me){
console.log(me.value);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<input type=checkbox value= 'omega.php' onchange = 'savevalue(this)' id='omega'><span id='omega1'>Omega(ω)</span></input>
<input type=checkbox value= 'psi.php' onchange = 'savevalue(this)' id='psi'><span id='psi1'>Psi(ψ)</span></input>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the checkboxes are inside a form whose submit button is id "form_submit", then you can try the following jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#form_submit').live('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if($('#phi').is(":checked")){
            window.location.href="'phi.pl";
        }else if($('#psi').is(":checked")){
            window.location.href="psi.pl";
        }else if($('#omega').is(":checked")){
            window.location.href="omega.pl";
        }else if($('#calpha').is(":checked")){
            window.location.href="calpha.pl";
        }else if($('#chi').is(":checked")){
            window.location.href="chi.pl";
        } else{
            alert("Invalid request!");
        }

});
```

Comment: **Please Note:** The `live()` method was deprecated in jQuery version 1.7, and removed in version 1.9. Use the `on()` method instead.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you.